# The "rel" attribute after function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button and it has rel attribute. On click of the button i am calling a validatePromo function and it does its task. I want to know how can we call the rel attribute once the function call is successful.

```
 <button type="submit" rel="next" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="vm.validatePromo()">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass the element as a parameter `ng-click="vm.validatePromo(this)"`?

Comment: @mplungjan its not working

Comment: @raul.vila i passed this as the parameter but doesnt work

Comment: You need to use it too. "It's not working" is the most useless phrase at SO.

Comment: @SukeshGurmekodi Passing the element is only the first step, you need to get the value inside `vm.validatePromo()` function and execute the `rel` param as you want.

Comment: @mplungjan Okay

Comment: Like `function validatePromo(theBut) { someFunctionArray[theBut.getAttribute("rel")]();  `

Comment: @raul.vila how can i execute this.rel from function ?

Comment: SukeshGurmekodi The code from @mplugjan can be useful. Buf if you don't know what are we talking about, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can test easily.